# Saving Option Menu InstateState Android

Tags: android, menu, save, instant

I have an option menu when the activity looses focus the selected option menu item(s) retain state but when my activity is destroyed all the options are reset.

How can I save the state of the selected preference after resuming from a destroyed state? Having problem visualizing how to implement [Shared Preferences][1] for the code.

(Only needed for the boolean values but I have included the static menu items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create some shared preferences.  Those, and other data storage options are described in [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Did you read the link?  It gives a very clear explanation of how to use shared preferences.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write your code for you.  If you make an attempt with the given example and run into a specific problem then we can help you debug that issue.